# Android expandableListAdapter Button

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to start a new activity or change the actual layout with a button click on a group of an expandableListAdapter, but without success so far because getFragmentManager is not recognized.

Could you help with this issue?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {


    final LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    switch (groupPosition) {
        case 0:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_standard_parameters, null);
            choiceCategory = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choiceCategory);
            seeTemplates = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.seeTemplates);

            String[] choice = {"", "Personnel", "Professionnel", "Administratif"};

            ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterR = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this._context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, choice);
            dataAdapterR.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            if (choiceCategory != null) {
                choiceCategory.setAdapter(dataAdapterR);
            }

            final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            dayNotif = (DatePicker) convertView.findViewById(R.id.dayNotif);
            dayNotif.init(year, month, day, null);

            seeTemplates.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    //method to see another layout

                }
            });
            break;
        case 1:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_advanced_parameters, null);
            choiceRepeatSpinner = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.choiceRepeat);
            String[] choiceRepeat = {"", this._context.getString(R.string.day),this._context.getString(R.string.week),this._context.getString(R.string.month),this._context.getString(R.string.year)};

                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterRepeat = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this._context,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,choiceRepeat);
                dataAdapterRepeat.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                if(choiceRepeatSpinner!=null) {
                choiceRepeatSpinner.setAdapter(dataAdapterRepeat);
                }
            break;
        case 2:
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_templates_alert,null);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using support library, you have to use

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
```

instead of getFragment manager

Comment: I have this line in my build.gradle :

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'

But getSupportFragmentManager(); is not defined because my class don't extends of a fragmentActivity.